# Python ООП и приватные атрибуты

Tags: python, ооп

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить замечание

Comment: никак. в `python`нет приватных атрибутов

Comment: Можно разве что сделать атрибут условно приватным (с помощью '_' в начале имени), но у вас это уже есть.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Одно подчёркивание - это больше соглашение. Два подчёркивания сделают аттрибут более "приватным". Интерпретатор переименует его для защиты от перекрытия тем же именем в наследниках: "__double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes _FooBar__boo; see below)."

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинку на текст. С меня плюсик.

Answer (score 2):

В Python нет модификаторов доступа, всё является public, но есть определённые соглашения, которые имитируют модификаторы доступа, на простом классе это легче всего показать.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.public = 'public'
        self._protected = 'protected'
        self.__private = 'private'


obj = Example()
print(obj.public,
      obj._protected,
      obj._Example__private, sep='\n')
```

Вывод

```
public
protected
private
```

Здесь отсутствие подчёркивание сигнализирует о том, что переменная является public. Одно подчёркивание о том, что переменная является protected и к ней не стоит обращаться вне класса-родителя или наследника. А два подчёркивания говорит о private-переменной. Но как можно увидеть, ничто нам не мешает обратиться к этим переменным. Поэтому конкретно в вашем случае скорее всего нужно добавить ещё одно подчёркивание (self.__data).

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Приватных атрибутов [не существует](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) в Python:

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

---

Замыкания также не позволяют добиться приватности, так как позволяют получить доступ к сохранённым данным через [`__closure__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__closure__#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self._password = password


def get_closure():
    user = User('nomnoms12', '_GrUnDy!')
    def get_public():
        return user.name
    return get_public


get_public = get_closure()        # <function get_closure.<locals>.get_public>
public = get_public()             # nomnoms12

private = get_public.__closure__  # (<cell: User object>,)
user = private[0].cell_contents   # <__main__.User object>
password = user._password         # _GrUnDy!
```

Comment: Это не вся правда. Двойное подчёркивание защищает от непреднамеренного доступа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Лишь от непреднамеренного. Но всё ещё оставляет член класса публичным: `Note that the mangling rules are designed mostly to avoid accidents; it still is possible to access or modify a variable that is considered private`

Comment: И всё же в рамках вопроса ещё одно подчёркивание может быть ответом.

Comment: А если воспользоваться замыканиями, то можно получить объект класса с полноценной инкапсуляцией. Хотя так никто не делает - овчинка выделки не стоит.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy python позволяет получить доступ к содержимому замыкания через атрибут `__closure__` (но это нужно быть очень преднамеренным, конечно)

Comment: @andreymal, ваша правда. Я то пытался спрятаться за замыканиями. Не выйдет. :)

Comment: @andreymal Ой, а можно ссылку на пример кода, о чём вообще речь с замыканиями, я так то про них знаю, но в этом контексте не соображу что происходит

Comment: @CrazyElf я тоже не соображу, просто игрался с обычными замыканиями обычных функций

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил пример того, как я это вижу