Python ООП вопрос про теорию
Для роста своего скила и улучшения понимания, задался вопросом про понимание наследования в Python./
У меня есть два класса родитель и наследник, имеющие приватный атрибут __n.
class A:
    __n = "a"

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(self.__n)


class B(A):
    __n = "b"


A()
B()

# a
# a

При наследовании из-за искажения имен доступ к новому значению __n утерян.
Я решаю эту проблему таким способом:
class A:
    __n = "a"

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(self.__true_n)

    @classmethod
    @property
    def __true_n(cls):
        return getattr(cls, f"_{cls.__name__}__n")


class B(A):
    __n = "b"


A()
B()

# a
# b

Хочу разобраться, существует ли более "правильный" или "Питоновский" способ получение доступа к атрибуту __n?

Информационно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432144/python-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B

Я бы сделал как-то так:
class A:
    __n= "Приват A"

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n

class B(A):
    __n = "Приват B"
    
    @property
    def nA(self):
        return super().n
        
    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n

obj_a = A()
obj_b = B()

print(obj_a.n)  
print(obj_b.nA)  
print(obj_b.n)  

Вывод:
Приват A
Приват A
Приват B

[Program finished]


Пример с использованием metaclass:
import re

class PrivateAccessMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_dct = dct.copy()  
        for key in new_dct.keys():
            if key.startswith(f'_{name}') and not key.endswith('__'):
                pattern = re.compile(r'_(\w+)__(.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
                result = pattern.search(key).group(2)
                dct.update({result: property(lambda self, prop=key: getattr(self, prop))})    
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass=PrivateAccessMeta):
    __n= "Приват A __n"
    __z= "Приват A __z"
    __y= "Приват A __y"
    __h= "Приват A __n"
    
class B(A, metaclass=PrivateAccessMeta):
    __n = "Приват B __n"

obj_a = A()
obj_b = B()
print(obj_a.n)
print(obj_a.z)
print(obj_b.n)
print(obj_b.z)
print(obj_b.y)

Вывод:
Приват A __n
Приват A __z
Приват B __n
Приват A __z
Приват A __y


Благодарю за ответ, я знаю он рабочий. Я наверно не совсем точно описал в вопросе, но я хочу при наследовании обходиться без лишних переопределений  методов, используя принцип "изменений в 1 точке".

@НаполовинуПолон дополнил пример.
